# Single Item Order - AdventureWorks

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am wondering if my answer works for this problem? The answer I was able to find on the internet seems similar but they join another table which seems ambiguous.

Question: 
A "Single Item Order" is a customer order where only one item is ordered. Show the SalesOrderID and the UnitPrice for every Single Item Order.

Their answer:

```
select sod.SalesOrderID, sod.UnitPrice
from SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail sod
inner join SalesLT.SalesOrderHeader soh on soh.SalesOrderID =
sod.SalesOrderID
where sod.SalesOrderID in (
                          select s.SalesOrderID as ordernums
                          from SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail s
                          group by s.SalesOrderID
                          having COUNT(*) = 1
                          );
```

My Answer:

```
SELECT SalesOrderID, UnitPrice
FROM SalesOrderDetail
GROUP BY SalesOrderID
HAVING COUNT(SalesOrderID) = 1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run your answer, you'll get an error because `UnitPrice` is not in the `GROUP BY`.  If you add it, your `HAVING` will not work.

The solution is simple . . . you need an aggregation function:

```
SELECT SalesOrderID, MAX(UnitPrice) as UnitPrice
FROM SalesOrderDetail
GROUP BY SalesOrderID
HAVING COUNT(SalesOrderID) = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you, Gordon.